# probe is not getting called in i2c driver

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

I am trying to learn to write a i2c driver on raspberry pi board and i have taken groove LCD back-light.Here driver.probe is not getting called whereas driver's inserted in system as i can see in dmesg.

Init code of driver is getting called, and code =>

```
static int lcd_probe(struct i2c_client *i2c_client, const struct i2c_device_id *i2c_id)
{
    int ret  = 0;
    //struct        lcd_data *lcd_data;
    // struct device *dev = &i2c_client->dev;
    // lcd_data->client = i2c_client;

    pr_debug("lcd_probe : calling the probe\n");
    pr_debug("lcd_probe : i2c_client->addr = %d, i2c_client_name = %s\n",
            i2c_client->addr, i2c_client->name);

    return ret;
}

static struct i2c_device_id lcd_id[] = {
    {"lcd", 0},
    {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(i2c, lcd_id);

static struct i2c_driver lcd_driver = {
    .driver = {
            .name = "lcd",
            .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    },
    .probe = lcd_probe,
    // .remove = lcd_remove,
    // .attach_adapter = lcd_attach,
    .detect = lcd_detect,
    .id_table = lcd_id,
};
static int __init lcd_init(void)
{
    pr_debug("lcd_init : calling init\n");
    return (i2c_add_driver(&lcd_driver));
}
```

and dmesg =>

```
[    1.971009] lcd_init : calling init
```

But driver.probe is not registering in i2c subsystem.
board file initialization =>

Board init code =>

```
/** start aartyaa lcd i2c driver */
printk(KERN_INFO "board file registering i2c lcd device\n");
i2c_register_board_info_dt(1, lcd_i2c_devices, ARRAY_SIZE(lcd_i2c_devices));
```

i2c_board_info code =>

```
/** aaryaa i2c lcd struct */
static struct i2c_board_info __initdata lcd_i2c_devices[] = {
    {
            .type = "lcd",
            .addr = 0x62,
    },
};
```

i added debugs in i2c_register_device 
and i found driver prove device is not getting called. dmesg i have  linked 
[dmesg link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5E-P9ncaKo5OTdoSVZCX1Z2Sm8)

It seems that i need to register  in platform also ..

How probe gets called in i2c ... ? 
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you...!!!

Comment: Did you add the entry for the device into the device tree?

Comment: As i know, i can provide client details through either DT or board file. Here i used board file. If i go wrong, please correct me. and why it is required to add in DT...?

Comment: I aleardy know bus num as I have used i2cdetect to detect the device on bus 1 with addr 0x62 and 0x3e. So can u plz explain in details.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a .detect method in your client driver.  That's for probing the bus.  It's likely you do not have the device for your driver to bind to.  Take a look in sysfs, you should see in /sys/bus/i2c/devices a directory named something like "0-0062", and in it should be a filed named "name", which should have the contents "lcd".  If you can't find that, the device entry is not there for the driver to bind to.

Comment: in sysfs i can see only symlink "i2c1" - > (../../../devices/platform/soc/20804000.i2c/i2c-1), which contains of "20804000.i2c" in  "name" file. So my device is not registered to sys. And  There is no device entry for lcd.  @tangrs suggested, I need to add device in DT. Pls correct me, If i go wrong ... !!

Comment: If you use board file for instatiating devices use i2c_register_board_info() instead of i2c_register_board_info_dt().